# Whats the meaning of the structure てたって?

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation, て-form

I saw this structure on the caption of the anime Batman Ninja, when Joker is speaking:

そこの猿野郎が俺たちの頭をいじくってたってわけで

I think the only thing I don't understand there is the たって, after the verb いじくる in the て form.

I think the translation is something like this: This stupid monkey (gorilla Grodd) tampered with our heads. (I think there is no translation for the words わけで in the end. They are just there to show that his afirmation is a conclusion of what he had seem happening on the moment.)

Comment: 「いじくっていたというわけで」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's いじくってた + ってわけで.

- いじくってた is a contracted version of いじくっていた (past progressive; "was V-ing")
- って is a colloquial variant of と or という.
- わけ (訳) means "reason" here. This whole sentence is supposed to be the reason or the clarification for what's discussed in the current context.

> そこの猿野郎が俺たちの頭をいじくってたってわけで。
> = そこの猿野郎が俺たちの頭をいじくっていたというわけで。
>
> (Because / It is that) the monkey over there was messing with our heads.